# Why `method_exists($scope, 'extend')` exists in method `withGlobalScope` of Laravel's Buidler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I read the Laravel 5.3's source code, I find the following codes

```
public function withGlobalScope($identifier, $scope)
{
    $this->scopes[$identifier] = $scope;

    if (method_exists($scope, 'extend')) {
        $scope->extend($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I am confused about why it is the following codes in the method, is it used anywhere?

```
if (method_exists($scope, 'extend')) {
    $scope->extend($this);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's meant for extending the Builder within the context of a Scope class.

Inside a global Scope (class which extends the Scope interface), you can create an extend function next to the apply function.

This extend function is called with the Eloquent builder as parameter. Imagine some PopularUsersScope, which only gets very popular users:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model): void
{
    $builder->join(...)->where(...) // determine popularity
}


public function extend(Builder $builder)
{
    $builder->macro('demote', function (Builder $builder) {
        return $builder->update(...) // query to make user not so popular
    });
}
```

Now lets have a model Clan, which is a group of users, some of which are popular. We have a constrained relation on Clan:

```
public function popular_users(): belongsToMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class)
        ->withGlobalScope('popularUsers', new PopularUsersScope)
}
```

Because we defined a macro within the scope extend function, we can do `$user->demote()` for any popular user, but not for normal users.

This might be a bit of a silly example, but it can be useful in fairly abstract use cases.

See [SoftDeletingScope](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletingScope.php) in the Laravel Framework code for a practical example: SoftDeletable items need some extra methods on the Builder for restoring and eager loading deleted items.

Extend in SoftDeletingScope dynamically adds multiple extensions to the Builder, from an Array `$this->extensions`, and registers an replacement for the default delete function on the model:

```
public function extend(Builder $builder)
{
    foreach ($this->extensions as $extension) {
        $this->{"add{$extension}"}($builder);
    }

    $builder->onDelete(function (Builder $builder) {
        $column = $this->getDeletedAtColumn($builder);

        return $builder->update([
            $column => $builder->getModel()->freshTimestampString(),
        ]);
    });
}
```